# jq: Create JSON Object from flat keys

Tags: json, object, key, jq

How can I create a nested JSON object from the flat keys in an object with jq?

My input is

```json
{
    "foo.bar": "lorem",
    "foo.baz": "ipsum",
    "bar.foo": "dolor"
}
```

and the output should look like

```json
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "lorem",
        "baz": "ipsum"
    },
    "bar": {
        "foo": "dolor"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way uses `reduce` and `setpath` to build up the new object from the keys of the original:

```sh
$ jq '. as $orig | reduce keys[] as $key ({}; setpath($key | split("."); $orig[$key]))' input.json
{
  "bar": {
    "foo": "dolor"
  },
  "foo": {
    "bar": "lorem",
    "baz": "ipsum"
  }
}
```

---

How it works

`reduce` calls the expression in its body once per key. The first time, `.` is set to an empty object, each other time it's what the body of the previous call returned. Each call splits the current key up into an array, and `setpath` uses that as a path to set in `.` using the corresponding value from the original object.

So the result is gradually built up one element at at time:

`.` = `{}` and `$key` = `"foo.bar"` -> `.` = `{"foo":{"bar":"lorem"}}` and `$key` = `"foo.baz"` and so on.